# This expression has type 'a -> 'a array array but an expression was expected of type 'b array

Tags: dynamic, ocaml

How is it possible to correctly manipulate a matrix in Ocaml?
What am I missing here, when assigning a value to a position on the matrix?

```
let dynamic arraymoedas valor len =
    let arrayAux = Array.make_matrix (len+1) (len+1) in
    for i=0 to len+1 do
        arrayAux.(i).(0)=0;
    done;
    for j=0 to valor+1 do
        arrayAux.(0).(j)= max_int 
    done;
    for i=1 to len+1 do
        for j=1 to len+1 do
            if(arraymoedas.(i-j) > j) then
                arrayAux.(i).(j) = arrayAux.(i - 1).(j)
            else
                arrayAux.(i).(j) = min (1+arrayAux.(i).(j-arraymoedas.(i - 1))) arrayAux.(i-1).(j)

        done;
    done;
    !arrayAux
```

Error:

```
File "Novo_func.ml", line 38, characters 8-16:
38 |         arrayAux.(i)(0)=0;
             ^^^^^^^^
Error: This expression has type 'a -> 'a array array
       but an expression was expected of type 'b array
```

Comment: https://ocaml.org/api/Array.html
Check the doc you're not using `make_matrix` properly : you need an init value. Also to assign a value use `myarray.(i).(j) <- value` instead of `=`

Comment: @Butanium has the answer but I will add: since you left out one of the parameters of `make_matrix`, you're defining `arrayAux` to be a function. (This is how things work when functions are curried.) That's why the error message says you're supplying a function where you need an array.

Comment: One more note: in the final line of code you posted `!arrayAux` you are using the `!` operator which has type `'a ref -> 'a` on an `int array`, not an `int array ref` so this will not work.

Answer (score 1):

As identified in the comments, there are three issues with the code you've written.

Primarily, you're not using `Array.make_matrix` properly. This function has type `int -> int -> 'a -> 'a array array`. You've only supplied the dimensions, but not a default value. When you do this, you get back a function that takes in the default value and returns an array of arrays.

Secondly, when modifying the values in an array, use `<-` instead of `=`. Rather than `arrayAux.(0).(j) = max_int` you want to use `arrayAux.(0).(j) <- max_int`.

Thirdly, at the end of your `dynamic` function, you're using the `!` operator to deref `arrayAux`. The problem with this is that `arrayAux` is not a reference. This will cause a compiler error due to a type mismatch.